# write React.js apps with Javascript or with Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am new to React.js and right now I am learning it. 
Now I am not sure if I should learn React writing Code in Javascript or in Typescript. 
There are more tutorials online which teach you React using JS, but I personally like TS more.
What language would you recommend to build React.js apps

Comment: Use typescript, ask specific questions on stack when you have something in JS you con't use in TS ? But that is just an opinion ..

Comment: This question is primarily opinion-based. FWIW, my view is react+TS works fine, and is great for learning both. However, if you're working against a deadline, the added overhead of building a robustly-typed react application is *usually* not worth it, especially once you start adding other libraries like redux. In my current projects I use TS only sparingly, and only where I feel it adds the most value.

Comment: @p.s.w.g can you write js Statements in .TS files?

Comment: @clem995 Yes, TS is a syntactic extension to JS, so (assuming you have the right TSLint settings) *nearly* any valid JS is also valid TS. However, in my projects I use different build settings between `.js`, `.ts`, and `.tsx` (TS+React) files, this makes sure I follow the right set of rules while coding.

Comment: It's a good question, so I think it should be reopened. However, it needs to be re-formulated more narrow like "What's the official React team recommendation?", "What are cons\pros of either choices from experienced React developers", etc and reopened. Those answers would provide a good guidance for novices in React.

Answer (score 5):

It's certainly confusing which option to go for - so I understand why you ask the question

I spent around two years working with JavaScript before being introduced to TypeScript through Angular. I love working with TS now, particularly the code completion I get in VSCode, and the ability to statically type models and params with Interfaces - very helpful in large teams

Saying that, I'm glad I had a solid JS foundation before picking up TS. I would advise learning React with JavaScript until you are very comfortable with it. Also, the React community is predominantly using JS, so that should be a key consideration

Comment: thank you for your answer :)